# How can I retain an activity as a singleton

Tags: android, android-activity, vuforia

I have an activity that scans images and takes pictures. I am using the Vuforia library to scan these images, and I have no control over the implementation of the code that handles the camera.

This activity needs to be shown multiple times in the lifecycle of the app, but it takes a while to start up the camera each time.

Is there a way I can retain only one instance of this activity? So that I only need to pause the camera, so it takes less time loading the camera?

So I either want to store this activity somewhere and display it when I need it, or have a way to keep it on the screen, but behind the other activities.

Comment: if i got it... I think you need to use activity launch mode..

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [singleTask launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html?hl=id#lmode). An Activity with this launchMode is allowed to have only one instance in the system.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="activity name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

From the documentation:

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes
>   the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a
>   call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Okay, so I place this in my manifest on the activity I want only one of? And each time I start an intent for this activity, the same one appears? How can I close that activity? `finish()` just finishes the activity.

Comment: Yes you only need to add it in manifest once. Each time you start the activity, the old activity, if there, will be used. Everything is the same except that you need to handling for the intent in `onNewIntent()`

Comment: How can I go back to a previously shown activity while keeping this one alive? I can’t use finish()

Comment: How about using `moveTaskToBack()`  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29 ?

Comment: That just moves my entire app to the background